# file modification time as integer in C

Tags: c, time

I have seen and tried different ways in displaying the time a file was last modified and I'm using the C programming language.

What I want to achieve is the least CPU intensive function to determine the time a given file is modified, but instead of displaying it as a string or displaying parts of the string, I want to store it as a large integer so I can do math on it later.

So basically I want to mimic the operation of PHP's filemtime but in C since I'm writing an apache module.

Any ideas how to go about this or ideas on what good functions to use to achieve this without making something super lengthy?

Comment: Try  `stat()` (`st_mtime` field of `struct stat`)?

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, kindly accept it, for the convenience for other viewers of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could declare a `stat` struct and use `stat( )` to get the file details in the `stat` structure defined.

Example Code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct stat file_details;
  stat("homework.txt", &file_details);
  time_t modify_time = file_details.st_mtime; 
  printf("Last modified : %lld",modify_time);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know how you would manage math on it, but here's your `modify_time` in a `time_t {aka long int}`.

Comment: Why `*(&file_details.st_mtime)` and not just `file_details.st_mtime`?

Comment: Oops. You are right. I'll edit it. Thanks a lot, @Dmitri

Comment: Your code doesn't need anything from `<time.h>` when written as shown.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot for the edit suggestion, @JonathanLeffler.

Comment: Why use `long int` when field `st_mtime` is of type `time_t`?

Comment: @chux: what's the correct `printf()` format specifier for `time_t`?  Short answer, there isn't one.  So, using `long` is reasonable on a 64-bit system if you cast to the type; using `long long` is reasonable on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems if you cast to the type.  You could use `intmax_t` from `<stdint.h>` for the type and `PRIdMAX` from `<inttypes.h>` (which includes `<stdint.h>` anyway) for the format specifier.  Nothing works reliably without the cast, AFAIK.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler OP wanted to "do math on it later" so converting from `time_t` to `long` unnecessarily risks truncation. I was wondering why this answer changed type to `long`.  Printing the value was not listed at OP's goal: "but instead of displaying it".  As C does not specifier a format specifier for `time_t`, the better solution is keep the time as type `time_t` and cast to a wide format specifier `imtmax_t`:  `time_t mtime = ... printf("jd", (intmax_t) mtime)` for printing. Of course `time_t` may not be the typical seconds since Jan 1, 1970 and a robust solution would account for that.

Comment: @chux: OK — I see what you mean, and I mis-assumed (mis-read) the code.  I was looking at the `printf()` line, not noticing that the type on the line before was `long`. My bad! Nominally, on non-POSIX systems, `time_t` can be a non-integer type.  POSIX requires it to be an integer type.  It's fiddly at the moment. Historically, it was often a (32-bit) `long` value, but that is only good for the 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 epoch for another 23 years.  Many systems have switched to a 64-bit `time_t` (good enough for the lifetime of the universe or thereabouts), but it's a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It took me 20 mins to find the right functions but I managed to roll off this function to return the time as an actual number:

F in the function means filename and when I called the function, I passed the file as a hard-encoded string.

```
time_t filemodtime(char *f){struct stat attr;stat(f,&attr);return time(&attr.st_mtime);}
```

Comment: It was looking good up until the return statement.  That then screws things up completely by returning the current time every time.  It also modifies the value stored in the local variable `attr.st_mtime` with the current time.

Comment: I'll have to take a look. I did notice duplicate times when comparing with time(null)

Comment: I changed it up a bit but I think I'm missing something since I have the same result.

`time_t filemodtime(char *f){struct stat attr;stat(f,&attr);time_t tm=time(&attr.st_mtime);return tm;}`

Comment: Rather than `time_t tm=time(&attr.st_mtime);return tm;`, suggest `return attr.st_mtime`.  Might want to check the result of `stat()` to see it it succeeded.

Comment: Ok, so the times are different but now I am looking for a way to get the difference between now and file time. I tried difftime() function by importing the return value from the above function and using time(NULL) as parameters. The result returned is zero. I tried encapsulating time() around the return value from the function and still no success. Is there another function I could try?

Comment: The `difftime()` function is an artefact of the C89/C90 standardization that does not mandate that `time_t` is an integer type, unlike POSIX which does.  So, `difftime()` returns the difference as a `double` value.  If you're on a POSIX-ish system, you can simply subtract the two `time_t` values and get a (signed) integer type as the result (of the type `time_t`).

Comment: Your function should probably be `file_age_in_seconds()` if it returns a difference between the current time and the modification time: `time_t file_age_in_seconds(const char *filename) { struct stat attr; if (stat(filename, &attr) == 0); return attr.st_mtime - time(0); else return -1; }` (with error check added).

Comment: It does change the value but it doesn't seem right. I test the program like once a second. I'll see what else I can do to make it work